# How to useRef in Hoc for html element using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-ref, react-hoc

This is my code

```js
import React, { FC, InputHTMLAttributes, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

type TElementType = HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement;
type TElementWithAttributes = InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>;

interface Props {
  submitTouched: boolean;
}

const withInput = (Comp: FC<TElementWithAttributes>): FC<Props> => props => {
  const { submitTouched } = props;

  const refValue: React.RefObject<TElementType> = useRef(null);

  const updateErrors = (val: string) => {
    // handle errors
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (submitTouched && refValue.current) {
      updateErrors(refValue.current.value);
    }
  }, [submitTouched]);

  const InputOrTextarea = (
    <>
      <Comp name="somename" type="text" value="somevalue" ref={refValue} />
    </>
  );
  return InputOrTextarea;
};

export default withInput;
```

I am getting error on ref={refValue}

> Type '{ name: string; type: string; value: string; ref: RefObject; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & TElementWithAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
> Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & TElementWithAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ref` is added to the html props by `React.DetailedHTMLProps` that is why you are getting an error. Try:

```
type TElementType = HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement;
type TElementWithAttributes = React.DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<TElementType>, TElementType>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0BvOcBiAwpnAJIB2YArjABIAqAsgDICCMMUwARjUgM4kq-JAFEAZuKQYhI5OLgBfOOKgQQcAORRUGTQG4AUIZgBPMEjj1RAGyQgk5GPXOWAvHAYsK1GLfuO8AA+nkzM9EgAHjCsOij+Dk5GZhZWCYEA6sAwABbsnDx8-HAeyOgwAHQAIkgwKMB2ACZezAAKamD8ADw+NC35XLwwAl3WdonOrgB8JGMBTi4WU4Z4xsBOSFDi6JbtEJ1w2Ctw-FTcINn0EFRoOUiNAFxw3BAQdijkRorGaBDk-PAAO7ZHK9eAeAAUhHUYCeRFG6ScWVyA0Kw34UwAlHDCF09p0piVCWAOsU3ISjnhfv94LhTudLtdbvclCU4CT9vwjMdqQC4DpxAA1FA2KhIJ5lDAVeQAeW4ACtpDAEeNAoskISPMIkPIIeQqDYbJjuVS-nyqGBGihhqIoGooGS4BCAG4ip4ArjkADmmKJh2OeAA9IG4DkPo07HBNvb+MdFCa4NqJFIMBCIb7yf68HhgAoIfSLs4mXdGnAAGRl-lIIUisUVNBUO2BX2U7N4C1Wm126D8CEC4WipD1xs6JwVV2D40BpRxkgAbQLjJuJYAulOeWb4GCZVAItEUHE2RDp11lm28F1oeA4OQUA43AAifjqRx3pAPuApJCP4bRD8TsVH2fBwAPfKtxDcbB+1rJBlDgQMz2zLoEOOKc8B0GBG3IMhKBoHc9zqOIvm5KJIFgOBGmrFADSBEEwX0IA)